# Understanding Formulas in First Order Logic

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm reading a text on Set Theory which states that any formula, say $\phi$, is ultimately built up from atomic sentences of form $x \in y$ and $x = y$ via the logical connectives.

So then my question is as follows: suppose in reading this text I come upon a formula of form $\phi(x,y,z)$.  Am I to interpret this formula as ultimately a claim about membership and equality?  If $x,y,z$ are fixed, is $\phi(x,y,z)$ just really the claim $(x,y,z,1) \in \phi$ where $\phi$ is interpreted as a predicate function?

If this post isn't clear, here is really the question I'm getting at: how am I supposed to interpret statements like $\phi(x,y,z)$ when reading a book concerning axiomatic set theory written in the language of first-order logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you meet $\phi(x,y,z)$ then you know two things:

1. $\phi$ is a formula, in this case written in the language of set theory which only includes $\in$ (and $=$ which is part of the logical symbols).
2. $x,y,z$ denote the free variable which *may* (and usually do) occur in $\phi$.

This means that $\phi$ can be something like $x\in y\lor x=z$. But it also means that $\phi$ can be something much much much more complicated: $$(\exists w(x\in w\rightarrow y\notin z)\lor\forall w(y\in w\rightarrow z\in x))\rightarrow\exists w\forall u(u\in x\leftrightarrow x\in w\land y\in u)$$

These formulas come in two common flavors: as a general statement whose content doesn't *really* matter for us right now, we may be interested in its structure (in particular in the quantifiers it has inside), but not in its content; and sometimes it will be a statement similar to "*Let $\phi(x,y,z)$ be a formula saying that $x$ is an ordinal, and $y$ is a bijection from $x$ onto $z$*", in which case this is exactly how you should understand it.

Comment: Your last paragraph starts a bit awkward (there is no counterpart to "either"). (On second reading that's not entirely true, but it's not really an archetype of perfect formulation.)

Comment: I'm just really tired. I'll re-read it, and correct what needs to be corrected in a few hours.